# Edge Browser: document.execCommand("copy") command is not working in AJAX success callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, microsoft-edge

I have tried the following in the `fetch` success callback, but it fails and returns `false`. This issue occurs in **Edge** browser.

```
document.execCommand('copy')
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="toCopy">
    new value 12345
    <br /><br />
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

**Backbone JS  code:**

```
toCopy = Backbone.Model.extend({});
toCopy.fetch({
  "id": "xxx",
}).done(function(resp) {

  if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById("toCopy"));
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  }
  document.execCommand("copy");
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.execCommand copy command does not work or other solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253634/document-execcommand-copy-command-does-not-work-or-other-solution)

Comment: Perhaps, you could do something which I mentioned here:
[SOLVED: document execCommand copy not working with AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380921/not-able-to-copy-a-link-directly-when-i-am-using-ajax/43381458#43381458)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document execCommand copy not working with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380921/document-execcommand-copy-not-working-with-ajax)